# Prevent Blazor Mud Snackbar from opening across different browser sessions

Tags: c#, blazor, snackbar, mudblazor

I've followed the guide here on creating a MudBlazor Snackbar notification on a Blazor server app:
https://mudblazor.com/components/snackbar
However when I publish my site, and invoke the "ShowSnackbar" method below on a user machine, I see the snackbar showing across all browser sessions, even across different machines.

```
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar

<MudButton OnClick="ShowSnackbar"></MudButton>

@code {
public async void ShowSnackbar()
{
    Snackbar.Add($"Snackbar ID: {Guid.NewGuid()}", Severity.Normal);
}
}
```

[image: Snackbar shown across multiple instances]

How can I restrict this to show only on the session on which the button was clicked?

I copied the code directly from the MudBlazor site, expecting it to behave the way it does on their page:

As you can see, I click the Open Snackbar button here, and it only shows on 1 session.

[image: MudBlazor Snackbar showing only in 1 instance]

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing how your `Snackbar` is declared. I can see it coming from dependency injection and so this appears to be a scoping issue. The behavior you describe would be expected if you declared it to be singleton like so:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISnackbar, SnackbarService>();
```

If you instead declare it to be scoped then it will have a scope limited to connection, which sounds like the behavior you want.

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISnackbar, SnackbarService>();
```